# How to build openSSH with NSS or GnuTLS instead of OpenSSL?

Tags: openssl, openssh, nss, gnutls, libressl

Due to security issues with OpenSSL, I would like to use NSS or GnuTLS instead. For Apache server needs, it is easy since there exist a module for each one. But for SSH, it looks like difficult if not impossible.

Dropbear embeds its own algorithms and is not open to the outside. OpenSSH has used to being built with OpenSSL, but since a few months, [it is possible to build it without it](http://it.slashdot.org/story/14/04/30/1822209/openssh-no-longer-has-to-depend-on-openssl) thanks to the new option:

```
make OPENSSL=no
```

But then software cryptographic algorithms are used from D. J. Bernstein works. This is good, but not for me because I shall use a TPM, and so have access to a pkcs11 layer. As a consequence, the right solution would be to build OpenSSH with either NSS or GnuTLS.

I cannot wait for [LibReSSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LibreSSL) on Linux, nor use OpenBSD which has just released it and made it its SSL default layer.

So my question is: Has someone tryed and managed to build OpenSSH with NSS or GnuTLS instead of OpenSSL, or patched Dropbear or any other solution to have a SSH server working with a TPM and EC authentication ?

Note: as I have limited resources, I cannot use OpenSSL with OpenSSH and NSS with Apache. I absolutely need to minimize the embedded libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have identified three solutions:

1. Use [NSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/NSS) with [Nss compat ossl](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Nss_compat_ossl) that offers a 80% compatible OpenSSL API.
2. Use [GnuTLS](http://www.gnutls.org/) with its [OpenSSL compatibility layer](http://www.gnutls.org/manual/gnutls.html#Compatibility-with-the-OpenSSL-library) (I have not checked the coverage).
3. Go on with OpenSSL and move to OpenBSD's [LibReSSL](http://www.libressl.org/) or Google's [BoringSSL](http://arstechnica.com/security/2014/06/google-unveils-independent-fork-of-openssl-called-boringssl/) when available. The first one is already available on OpenBSD and they manage a portability project towards other *n*x distributions, so I assume it will be available for Linux in some months. Tremendous [cleaning and improvements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LibreSSL) have been performed.

Comment: I know this answer is old, but can you describe which solution you chose in the end? I am facing the same question and I would like to go with 2) but I just can't figure out how.

Comment: Unfortunatly, I moved. But please post when you have something working.

Answer (score 1):

No. But you may be able to reduce the increase on disk usage related to OpenSSL by linking libcrypto (which is the part of OpenSSL that OpenSSH actually uses) statically into `sshd`.

On my system I can do that by manually running the following command after `make sshd`:

```
gcc -o sshd sshd.o auth-rhosts.o auth-passwd.o auth-rsa.o auth-rh-rsa.o audit.o \
  audit-bsm.o audit-linux.o platform.o sshpty.o sshlogin.o servconf.o serverloop.o \
  auth.o auth1.o auth2.o auth-options.o session.o auth-chall.o auth2-chall.o \
  groupaccess.o auth-skey.o auth-bsdauth.o auth2-hostbased.o auth2-kbdint.o \
  auth2-none.o auth2-passwd.o auth2-pubkey.o monitor_mm.o monitor.o monitor_wrap.o \
  kexdhs.o kexgexs.o kexecdhs.o kexc25519s.o auth-krb5.o auth2-gss.o gss-serv.o \
  gss-serv-krb5.o loginrec.o auth-pam.o auth-shadow.o auth-sia.o md5crypt.o \
  sftp-server.o sftp-common.o roaming_common.o roaming_serv.o sandbox-null.o \
  sandbox-rlimit.o sandbox-systrace.o sandbox-darwin.o sandbox-seccomp-filter.o \
  sandbox-capsicum.o -L. -Lopenbsd-compat/  -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,-z,noexecstack \
  -fstack-protector-strong  -lssh -lopenbsd-compat \
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a -ldl -lutil -lz -lnsl  -lcrypt -lresolv
```

(that's the result of replacing `-lcrypto` for the full path to `libcrypto.a` and removing the `-pie` flag from the linker command generated by `make`).

Then, running `strip` on `sshd` reduces its size to roughly 2MB.

Obviously that makes sense if you are only going to ship `sshd` on the device. If you need `ssh` also there, it becomes useless.

Comment: Thanks salva. The point is that I want to avoid OpenSSL stuff. I am investigating GnuTLS and NSS wrappers that deliver an OpenSSL API. But they provide a subset only. I have to check if it is enough for my needs or not.